# how to properly insert c# code in to theese forms on this webpage?

Tags: c#, forum

```
private void Form1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Opacity = 1.0;
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your question. At the moment I have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: Fixed what? Your formatting? Code and Pre blocks aren't necessary, either indent by 4 or more spaces or just hit the 101010 button to format a selection as code.

Comment: Brandon you fixed it aye,, now the color tags for the code is showing, but how shold i past it in to the textboxes?

Comment: Questions about how to use SO should be asked on meta.stackoverflow.  Or better yet, read the online help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paste your code, select it, and press the "101 010" button, or press the control+k shortcut.

Comment: What is this 101010 button? 101010 = 42(decimal) = "(ascii) = *(ansi)
= confused

Comment: It's in the button bar above the area where you type your questions and answers. It marks the selected text as code.

Comment: ty that was what i needed, and 2*42 is 84, 84/7 is 12 and 12 in hex is C so actually C is the answer to life.

Comment: @Darkmage 84 / 7 ... The 7 comes from 42 / 6. And 6 comes from the 12 divided by 2. And the 2 used to multiply 42 in the first place. That's recursion in insanity.